# Recovering data from previous Ubuntu install

Tags: system-installation

I had hard drive issues on my dual boot XP/Ubuntu machine, I replaced the hard drives and I am trying to find data from my old Ubuntu install in the old drive, but I cannot find my file directory at all, where in the Ubuntu install is my data stored?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in your home directory at `/home/username`